# Cómo elimino los espacios en blanco generados por FlexBox?

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

Mi problema es el siguiente. Quiero que el primer Contenedor (.pop-up-title) tenga menos alto que el segundo (.suscription). El primer contenedor tiene un alto de 400 pixeles y el segundo tiene un alto de 440px. Ambos contenedores se encuentran dentro de un Padre Flexbox.

El problema es que el primer contenedor adopta el alto del segundo, agregándose unos espacios en blanco arriba y abajo del primer contenedor. Como hago para quitar estos espacios vacios? Alguna Solucion?

Aqui les comparto la captura de pantalla y mi codigo Html y CSS.

[image: El problema en pantalla]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Raleway;
}

.pop-up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.651);
}

.pop-up-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 950px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
}

.pop-up-title {
  flex-basis: 0;
  height: 400px;
  flex-grow: 1.3;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('office.jpg');
  background-size: 160%;
  background-position: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.pop-up-title h2,
.pop-up-title p {
  z-index: 999;
}

.pop-up-title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e43f5ac0;
}

.suscription {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 2;
  background: #fff;
  height: 440px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #1F4068;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ventana Modal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pop-up">
    <div class="pop-up-wrap">
      <div class="pop-up-title">
        <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="suscription">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="sub-content">
          <h2>Suscribete</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
          <form>
            <input type="email" value="Escribe tu correo electronico">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Suscripcion">
          </form>
          <div class="pop-up-social-items">
            <img src="icons8-play-button.svg" alt="">
            <img src="icons8-facebook.svg" alt="">
            <img src="icons8-instagram.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Recien me di cuenta que el problema es por la sombra. El problema es que la sombra no se adapta al alto del pop-up-title (primer contenedor). Como podria solucionar esto?

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, evita usar mayúsculas sostenidas en el sitio. Se asimila a gritos y entiendo que no es la idea :)

Comment: ¿Y en vez de esos espacios en blanco que es lo que pretendes que se vea? Si una de las columnas tiene de altura 400px s y la otra 440px a algún lado tienen que ir esos 40px de diferencia.

Comment: Según veo los dos contenedores tienen el espacio deseado, lo que pasa es que estás alineandolos en el contenedor padre con "align-items: center;", lógicamente se centran veticalmente, si quitas la linea se posicionará a la altura del segundo, aunque siempre verás el espacio sobrante abajo, eso es lógico ya que no tienen el mismo tamaño.

Answer (score 1):

Realicé unas modificaciones con respecto a al shadow, ya que lo estabas aplicando al contenedor principal cuando lo ideal es que cada caja tenga el suyo, también agregé un :before a la caja mas grande:

Opcionalmente puedes crear clases coincidentes para que englobes propiedades css repetidas y de esta forma optimizar el código.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Raleway;
}

.pop-up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.651);
}

.pop-up-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 950px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.pop-up-title {
  flex-basis: 0;
  height: 400px;
  flex-grow: 1.3;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('office.jpg');
  background-size: 160%;
  background-position: center;
  background: #e43f5ac0;
  color: #fff;
}

.pop-up-title h2,
.pop-up-title p {
  z-index: 999;
}

.pop-up-title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  z-index: -1
}

.suscription {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 2;
  background: #fff;
  height: 440px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;

}

.suscription:before {
    content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  z-index: -2;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #1F4068;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop-up">
    <div class="pop-up-wrap">
      <div class="pop-up-title">
        <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="suscription">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="sub-content">
          <h2>Suscribete</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
          <form>
            <input type="email" value="Escribe tu correo electronico">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Suscripcion">
          </form>
          <div class="pop-up-social-items">
            <img src="icons8-play-button.svg" alt="">
            <img src="icons8-facebook.svg" alt="">
            <img src="icons8-instagram.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero quitar la altura del pop-up-title y colocar stretch al pop-up-wrap

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Raleway;
}

.pop-up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.651);
}

.pop-up-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 950px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
}

.pop-up-title {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1.3;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('office.jpg');
  background-size: 160%;
  background-position: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.pop-up-title h2,
.pop-up-title p {
  z-index: 999;
}

.pop-up-title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e43f5ac0;
}

.suscription {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 2;
  background: #fff;
  height: 440px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #1F4068;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ventana Modal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pop-up">
    <div class="pop-up-wrap">
      <div class="pop-up-title">
        <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="suscription">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="sub-content">
          <h2>Suscribete</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
          <form>
            <input type="email" value="Escribe tu correo electronico">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Suscripcion">
          </form>
          <div class="pop-up-social-items">
            <img src="icons8-play-button.svg" alt="">
            <img src="icons8-facebook.svg" alt="">
            <img src="icons8-instagram.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero no es lo que queria. Con el codigo que me acabas de compartir los 2 contenedores tienen el mismo tamaño. pero yo quiero que el pop-up-title tenga menos altura.

Comment: Recien me di cuenta que el problema es por la sombra. El problema es que la sombra no se adapta al alto del pop-up-title (primer contenedor). Como podria solucionar esto?